Why don't static magnets attract copper wires?
I have a few simple magnets, like 1x2 cm (probably neodymium) magnets and similar smaller circular ones (similar to fringe magnets). They attract a (probably zinc or iron) wire: the wire is ~dark-grey, does not have insulation initially, is ~1-1.3 mm in diameter, and probably intended for some mechanical fixing, serving as a prop for plants etc (I bought it in a department store selling industrial goods for home).
But they do not attract a pure copper wire intended for electrical conduction: the wire had insulation initially (i removed the insulation), is ~orange color, is ~1-1.3 mm in diameter, I bought it in a store department intended specifically for electrical accessories. The magnets also do not attract a similar much thinner wire ~0.1-0.5 mm in diameter, intended for use in electrical circuits, which does not have insulation initially.
Why do such static magnets do not attract copper, if copper is a better conductor for electricity than iron or zinc?
Are there any effects/interactions/forces supposed to happen between a static magnet and a copper wire:

with a wire winded around a magnet
with a wire at some ~a few cm distance from the static magnet

with both placed in the air or in the soil (assuming there will be at least some random ionic or other charges in such environment)

Yes, partially. "In the case of copper it is the diagmagnetic contributions that wins and its total magnetic moment tends to (weakly) align copper samples against the magnetic field. " I am also interested what effects/interactions are supposed to happen at all between a copper wire and a static magnet placed in the air or soil
